# White Space Control With Spans

Tags: html, css

MDN [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace):

> whitespace at the start and end of elements and outside elements is ignored

However, why does the second paragraph render differently (space between words is colored in cyan)?  Why isn't the space colored in yellow in the third paragraph?

```css
p {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
p span:nth-child(1) {
  background: cyan;
}
p span:nth-child(2) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Hello,</span>
  <span>world!</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span> Hello, </span>
  <span>world!</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span>Hello,</span>
  <span> world! </span>
</p>
```

Comment: The P tag will just keep you contents in the same format as you wrote it. it is used to keep your "preformatted" text the same way as you wrote it.

Comment: `div` does the same.

Comment: i hope this can help you!

https://patrickbrosset.medium.com/when-does-white-space-matter-in-html-b90e8a7cdd33

Comment: Thanks!  Seems like the MDN documentation is oversimplifying things in this documentation.  Feel free to write an answer to this question, maybe it'll help others.  However, I still don't understand why it renders the third paragraph like the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote you mentioned,

> whitespace at the start and end of elements and outside elements is ignored

Is a *general* rule, applied to mostly block elements. There is some added nuance with inline elements, like your `<span>` elements. The browser will by default, collapse adjacent spaces in inline display contexts and use the first space encountered, even when they are contained in other inline elements. As step 4 of [the explanation on the same page you linked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace#explanation) states:

> any space immediately following another space (even across two separate inline elements) is ignored

Here we can follow the algorithm as outlined on the page to compare:

```html
<p>⏎
••<span>•Hello,•</span>⏎
••<span>world!</span>⏎
</p>
```

1. > First, all spaces and tabs immediately before and after a line break are ignored so

   ```html
   <p>⏎
   <span>•Hello,•</span>⏎
   <span>world!</span>⏎
   </p>
   ```
2. > Next, all tab characters are handled as space characters

   Irrelevant for us here.
3. > Next, line breaks are converted to spaces

   ```html
   <p>•<span>•Hello,•</span>•<span>world!</span>•</p>
   ```
4. > After that, any space immediately following another space (even across two separate inline elements) is ignored

   ```html
   <p>•<span>Hello,•</span><span>world!</span>•</p>
   ```

   Notice how the leading space in the first `<span>` has been collapsed, and the ending space has been kept, since it is the first space in the sequence of spaces, even across separate inline elements.
5. > And finally, sequences of spaces at the beginning and end of an element are removed

   ```html
   <p><span>Hello,•</span><span>world!</span></p>
   ```

---

```html
<p>⏎
••<span>Hello,</span>⏎
••<span>•world!•</span>⏎
</p>
```

1. > First, all spaces and tabs immediately before and after a line break are ignored so

   ```html
   <p>⏎
   <span>Hello,</span>⏎
   <span>•world!•</span>⏎
   </p>
   ```
2. > Next, all tab characters are handled as space characters

   Irrelevant for us here.
3. > Next, line breaks are converted to spaces

   ```html
   <p>•<span>Hello,</span>•<span>•world!•</span>•</p>
   ```
4. > After that, any space immediately following another space (even across two separate inline elements) is ignored

   ```html
   <p>•<span>Hello,</span>•<span>world!•</span></p>
   ```

   Notice how the leading space in the second `<span>` has been collapsed since the first space in the sequence is from outside of it, in the `<p>` element.
5. > And finally, sequences of spaces at the beginning and end of an element are removed

   ```html
   <p><span>Hello,</span>•<span>world!</span></p>
   ```